# Prove or give a counterexample for semi positive defined matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

$\newcommand{\lg}{\langle}$ $\newcommand{\rg}{\rangle}$
 A matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is semi positive defined if $\langle x, Ax \rangle = x^{T}Ax = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} x_{i}A_{ij}x_{j} \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.  Prove or give a counterexample

a)Let $v_{1},v_{2}, \ldots, v_{n}$ a basis of $R^{n}$. If $v_{j}^{T}Av_{j} \ge 0$ for all $1\le j \le n$ then $A$ is semi positive defined.

b) If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and satisfy $x^{T}Ax=x^{T}Bx$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ then $A=B$.

c)If $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is semi positive defined and symmetric then $\sqrt{A_{ii}A_{jj}} \ge |A_{ij}|$ for any $1\le i, j \le n$.

For a), is **false**. In $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, let $v_{1}=(1,0)$ and $v_{2}=(0,1)$ the canonical basis, and let $$A= \begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
-3 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation} $$
Then $v_{1}^{T} A v_{1}=0$ and $v_{2}^{T}Av_{2}=0$, but $(1,1) A \begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation} = -1 <0$.

b) **false** In $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, let $A=\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$ and $B=\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$, is easy to see thar for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, $A$ and $B$ satisfy $x^{T}Ax=x^{T}Bx$ but $A \neq B$.

c) I think is true, but I don't know how to prove it, it seems kind obvious but I don't see it.

Comment: I think that semipositive definite, positive definite are defined for symmetric matrices only, whereas in your counterexamples you are considering non - symmetric matrices.

Comment: The language of positive semi-definite is _usually_ reserved for symmetric matrices, which these are not. Your answer for a) is still correct, you can find a similar enough matrix that will work. For b) you will actually find that imposing symmetry might change the answer, see if you can see why!

Comment: @OsamaGhani oh! I didn't know, in my exercise the matrices are not necessarily symmetric matrices, until part c)., wich is the correct lenguage?, english is not my native lenguage, sorry for the mistakes

Comment: There isn't really anything comparable. I realize the question does not state that $A$ is symmetric, so based off of that, yes you're right. For $c$, my hint is to note that when you're symmetric,$A_{ij} = A_{ji}$, and consider that $\langle e_i, Ae_j \rangle = A_{ij}$, so there's an equivalent statement (that looks like an awful lot like Cauchy-Schwarz) that you could try showing.

Comment: @OsamaGhani  $\newcommand{\lg}{\langle}$ $\newcommand{\rg}{\rangle}$ Do I have to prove $(\langle e_{i},Ae_{i} \rangle) (\langle e_{j},Ae_{j} \rangle) \ge (\langle e_{i},Ae_{j} \rangle)(\langle e_{j},Ae_{i} \rangle)   $ right?

Comment: It's definitely an equivalent statement yes!

Comment: I can't prove it, can you please tell me another hint?